# Laravel many-to-many relationship with varying options

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and am attempting to set up a many to many relationship (at least I think that's what I need)

Essentially each user have preferences there are 7 types of preferences some preferences can have multiple values and some have only one value
Here are the **user_pref_options**

- project_type | ( will be checkboxes on view and have multiple options)
- favorite | (a user can have multiple this is a foreign key to another table)
- tagline | ( will be checkboxes on view and have multiple options)
- bedroom_min | (a single value per user)
- bedroom_max | (a single value per user)
- sf_min | (a single value per user)
- sf_max | (a single value per user)

and here is what the **user_pref table** has

| id | user_id | pref_option_id | value |

| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

| 3 | 1 | 2 | 364 |

| 4 | 1 | 2 | 201 |

| 5 | 1 | 2 | 9 |

| 6 | 1 | 2 | 244 |

| 7 | 1 | 2 | 192 |

| 8 | 1 | 2 | 292 |

| 9 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

| 10 | 1 | 11 | 1 |

| 11 | 1 | 12 | 6 |

| 12 | 1 | 13 | 1628 |

| 13 | 1 | 14 | 9134 |

so that would be 1 users notice how some option types have multiples

sorry I had to lay a lot of background before I ask my question.

I would like to be able to connect the user prefs to the user using Eloquent and am having trouble figuring out which way it should be done..

here is what I have tried

```
//User model
public function prefs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pref', 'pref_user', 'user_id', 'pref_id');
}
```

and

```
//Pref Model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pref', 'pref_user', 'user_id', 'pref_id');
}
```

I have taken a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

I would like to be able to get all the preferences and display them on a view 
(I won't bore you by pasting that in here now)

my struggle is that some of the preferences have multiple options and some have single options. How do I retrieve the values

maybe I need to separate each preference type to its own model but that seems like overkill I am open to suggestions

[image: Screenshot of View]

Answer (score 1):

`user_pref` table makes it difficult to distinguish between your prefs and also sets a lot of overhead data.
So, you can set the single value prefs (`bedroom_min`, `bedroom_max`, `sf_min` and `sf_max`) in `user` model or in separated model and retrieve them with `user`. And for other prefs, `many-to-many` relation is better and more flexible.
Finally, When you fetch User model, you will get the model and its relations.

Comment: I just liked the idea of all of my "preferences" being in one table but i can see how that becomes complicated because of the multiple lines. Thanks